# Power Query | Different column counts in PDF files

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to convert my several PDF files from the folder with Power Query to a CSV file.
The problem is the tables from PDF files have sometimes different count of columns.

The data has the same format in each file.

[image: Table structure from pdf pages]

it could be an example of the structure of my data from pdf.

And I would like to convert this to the following data structure.

[image: final result]

How can I transform the data, so that I could get text in one column and the amount in another, despite of the different column count from files?

Comment: See my updated version that matches the presumably more realistic data in your updated request. If you want to "select" certain columns, you will need to specify **how** you want to select them. Either manually or the criteria you will use.

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so please toggle checkmark next to that answer to mark issue solved, and perhaps upvote it with arrow

Answer (score 0):

You didnt provide any info that would help manipulate your PDFS

However, this powerquery pasted into home..advanced editor... will do the data transform you are asking for

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], 
//use your prior ending step name from any existing code in place of Source in next step, and remove above sample row
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Alpha", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.RemoveLastN(List.RemoveNulls(Record.FieldValues(_)),1), each Text.From(_)),",")),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Number", each  List.Last(List.RemoveLastN(List.RemoveNulls(Record.FieldValues(_)),1))),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Alpha", "Number"})
in #"Removed Other Columns"
```

[image]

this would let you specify columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Selection={"Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5","Column6","Column7"},
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Alpha", each let subset = Record.ToList(Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Index",Selection){[Index]}) in Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.RemoveLastN(List.RemoveNulls(subset),1), each Text.From(_)),",")),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Number", each let subset = Record.ToList(Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Index",Selection){[Index]}) in List.Last(List.RemoveNulls(subset),1)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",Selection&{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Thank you for th e suggestion, I think its a godd idea, but I have another problem, which my be I could mention before. The columns with text data sometimes have numbers also. 

May be following example could explain the structure of data

Comment: This will work regardless of what is is the columns. Did you test this solution at all?

Comment: I tested it, how can I specify the columns which i want to combine?

Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.RemoveLastN(List.RemoveNulls(Record.FieldValues(_)),1), each Text.From(_)),",")

Comment: edited to allow column selection. You need to specify that in your question next time

Answer (score 0):

***Edited to work with your updated example***

You can convert each row using the `List.Accumulate` function as shown below:

```
let

//Change next line to reflect the line that created
//  your example table in your posted question

    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],

//don't need the firstcolumn
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,Table.ColumnNames(Source){0}),

    #"Create Rows" = List.Accumulate(
        Table.ToRecords(#"Removed Columns"),
        #table({},{}), //create empty table
        (s,c)=> s & Table.FromColumns(
                        {{Text.Combine(List.RemoveLastN(List.RemoveNulls(Record.ToList(c)),1),"; ")}} &
                        {{List.Last(List.RemoveNulls(Record.ToList(c)))}},
                        type table[col1=text, col2=number]))
in
    #"Create Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: I thought the ABC was sample data. This would seem not to work for other text, or am I wrong ?

Comment: @horseyride You are not wrong. If the ABC might be whole words, it'd be simple to modify the algorithm to match whatever the real data is.